# 26 inch scale length good enough for Drop tuning guitar?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, tuning, alternative-tunings

I've recently been trying to drop tune to Drop G. I've read that a 27 inch scale length would be good but I was wondering if 26 would be okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be difficult to give you a specific answer. This really depends a lot on your specific expectations and compromises you'd like to make. What sound are you looking for. How thick strings are you willing to use. How low tension can you accept. Have you checked this on one of many string gauge/tension calculator available in the internet?

Have you tried putting thicker strings on a regular scale guitar and tune low? This may give you an idea where are you heading to.

The main reason for using long scale is the sound of the lowest string. 30" is frequently used scale for bass VI with E1-standard tuning. Low G1 note on third fret has then 25.25" active length on such guitar. So this *may* work. On the other hand 26" is typically considered as very short for baritone.

This video suggests at least 27" for G1 tuning

Here is another one showing 26.5" tuned to E1 with Evertune bridge

Evertune bridges solve some of intonation issues, but they bring their own "features", which may or may not be acceptable for you.